# Python pandas telebot

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, telegram

Цель: Рассылать задачи для сотрудников с помощью бота телеграмм

Вопросы: 1. При парсинге страницы excel, pandas не вытягивает все значение ячейки E2 добавляя лишь "...". Как можно парсить все содержимое ячеек для последующего вывода?? [image: Код]

2. Как при отправке сообщения через телеграм бота, отправлять именно таблицу, а не строки??

[image: Сообщение в телеграм]

Буду признателен за любой совет!

Comment: Вам будут все заинтересованные участники  очень признательны, если Вас не затруднит заменить картинки на текст воспользовавшись кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/878248/edit) . Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

`pd.read_excel()` читает/парсит *все* данные.

При преобразовании текстового столбца DataFrame в строку (для печати или при использовании `str()` или `df.to_string()`) Pandas обрезает длинные строки.

Максимальную длину строки (при преобразовании в строку) можно контролировать используя:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 100)
```

все доступные настройки:

```
In [209]: pd.options.display.
            pd.o…y.chop_threshold         pd.o…y.date_yearfirst         pd.options.display.html       pd.o…y.max_columns            pd.options.display.max_rows   pd.o…y.notebook_repr_html     pd.options.display.unicode
            pd.o…y.colheader_justify      pd.options.display.encoding   pd.options.display.large_repr pd.o…y.max_colwidth           pd.o…y.max_seq_items          pd.o…y.pprint_nest_depth      pd.options.display.width
            pd.o…y.column_space           pd.o…y.expand_frame_repr      pd.options.display.latex      pd.o…y.max_info_columns       pd.o…y.memory_usage           pd.options.display.precision
            pd.o…y.date_dayfirst          pd.o…y.float_format           pd.o…y.max_categories         pd.o…y.max_info_rows          pd.o…y.multi_sparse           pd.o…y.show_dimensions
```